# My bronco is having transmission issues

Tags: automatic-transmission, repair, truck, bronco

I have a 1996 full-size bronco with a 351W and an E4OD trans. I’m having to tach up to or past 3k rpm it to shift. It does way better in higher gears and reverse. Also, when i drop it into 1st and 2nd manually, it performs as it should. What’s going on here?

Comment: How many miles has it done? When was the trans fluid changed? Or checked? If the answers to these questions, in order, are : many, never, never... Then get it checked by a transmission specialist - it may need rebuild or replacement.

Comment: Are there any vacuum pipes connected to the gearbox?  If so, check that they are correctly connected and not leaking.

Comment: 207k miles. I’ve owned the truck for two years and it hasn’t had trans serviced. I’m on it this week. Thanks